# Best way to find the optimal point (slope=0) on a non-quadratic line?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression, scipy-optimize, polynomials

I'm working with a dataset that has the running count of products for a retailer on the x-axis, and the % of total revenue for the products on the y-axis (the max x-value will have a y-value of 100 (percent)). I'm using Python, Numpy, and Scipy to handle my data (and pandas of course).

My goal is to find the optimal count of products while still retaining a high % of the total revenue. Conceptually, I know this will be close to where the slope of the data first hits 0 (or close to 0). I first attempted this by trying to find the best fit of the line and was trying to fit quadratic and 2+ order polynomials, when I realized a) my data is not actually a quadratic shape and b) I do not really want to find the "best fit" as that will just simulate the current product assortment when the goal is to *reduce* the product assortment.

My next attempt was to plot a simple linear regression or single order polynomial, and for both methods the 2nd intersection of the line with my data actually hits a point that I think would be a good candidate for finding the "optimal" (retains 97% of the total revenue and reduces the line by ~26%).

My main concern is that while this method seems to work very well, I'm not sure if using a linear fit like this reflects a true "optimal" point, or if it just happens to get close to the true optimal.

I would really appreciate any insight into this. I do like my solution currently as it is easy to implement, repeatable, and requires simple coding, but I'm concerned it may not quite be accurate. If there is a better way to perform this optimization I would love to learn more about those methods.

Below is an example of my dataset. It is only the first 50 rows as the whole span is ~2000 rows. The y-data (RR_PCT) is a rolling percent-share of the revenue for each item, so I can perform other transformations to fit other methodologies if needed (normalization, etc).

RUNNING_CC_COUNT    RR_PCT
1   7.00
2   9.36
3   11.35
4   12.81
5   14.21
6   15.47
7   16.71
8   17.56
9   18.39
10  19.21
11  20.01
12  20.78
13  21.55
14  22.21
15  22.88
16  23.49
17  24.10
18  24.70
19  25.28
20  25.85
21  26.39
22  26.90
23  27.40
24  27.88
25  28.35
26  28.82
27  29.28
28  29.73
29  30.17
30  30.61
31  31.05
32  31.48
33  31.92
34  32.34
35  32.75
36  33.16
37  33.56
38  33.94
39  34.32
40  34.69
41  35.06
42  35.43
43  35.79
44  36.15
45  36.48
46  36.81
47  37.13
48  37.44
49  37.75
50  38.05

I've also included a graph showing my data, the linear function, and a vertical highlight at what I'm currently calling the "optimal" point.

[image: BLUE = DATA, ORANGE = ORDER 1 POLYNOMIAL, RED = VERTICAL LINE INTERSECTING "OPTIMAL" POINT]

Comment: The point you're showing does not have anywhere near a zero-slope, so what _really_ determines what you consider to be the "optimal" point?

Comment: What constitutes the "optimal count"?  You need to clearly define the function you are optimizing as the first step in the process.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I could have phrased my question better. Rephrasing “optimal point” in terms of my application: the minimum value of x (product count) with the maximum value of y (% of revenue)

Comment: In that case please [edit] your post (and probably title) to make that clear.

Comment: you see already now that you get with 400 products 80% of the revenues. So you could remove the other 800 products probably.  You will get a clearer picture if you associate the x "values" with production costs.